# Sharing resources between python processes

Tags: python

I am wanting to share multiple resources between multiple python scripts. Ideally what I am trying to do is run my main program. It contains some script wide variables. I then want to fork off the exact same program into a new shell and give it access to my script wide variables.

I am looking into multiprocessing but I am not sure if another way would be better such as using pipes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Value` and `Array` from `multiprocessing` for shared memory across processes.

Example from `multiprocessing`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#sharing-state-between-processes):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

will output:

```
3.1415927
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

Comment: Is it a pass by reference or pass by value? As in, if the newly created process modifies the variable, will the main process get the update?

Comment: `Value` and `Array` classes are abstractions for shared memory allocations, so yes, updates made to instances of these classes from any process will be reflected across all processes with access to the instances.

Comment: Is it possible to have this new process spawn into a new terminal window?

Comment: No, a new terminal window means a new shell, which breaks away from the `multiprocessing`-managed shared memory. If you need to spawn a new terminal window you would have to use `subprocess.Popen` and communicate with it via a pipe, with no shared memory possible.

Comment: I plan on having a client/server application. The server is going to be broken into two parts. The main program which handles all the connections and data received. Then I want to be able to open other shells, run the same program, but just receive data. So each shell gives me the ability to interact with a client that is connected to server. Would pipes be the way to do this? Would local sockets be better?

Comment: Seem like this is the same program you asked about in the other question I answered.  Basically what you need to do is only have ONE program which is your server and everything else connects to your server through a socket.  So everything else is a client.  But your clients can have different roles, by sending commands to the client when they connect or by connecting to different ports.