# What objects and variables are copied to child processes (by pickling) when I use Python 3 multiprocessing.pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm struggling to find answers on what objects and variables are copied to child processes when creating a multiprocessing pool in Python 3.

In other words, say I have a huge list (~230000000 elements) stored in a class that implements a function that uses a pool of four child processes. Will this list then be copied across to all four child processes if...

1. the child processes do not read from the list?
2. the child processes read from the list (however, the list is not modified)?

Comment: You haven't specified precisely *how* that class function uses the multiprocessing pool, i.e. what is being submitted to it and how. Nor have you tagged your question with the specific platform you are running on, which you are supposed to do for questions tagged with `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note***: this answer is partial in the sense that I too couldn't (yet) find written evidence and documentation about this, but the following gives some kind of empirical data, if you will.

---

The following code is used to demonstrate how data is being passed/copied to child processes using a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) (the actual list `l` is not used on purpose in the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) to allow clean printings):

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def process(x):
    print(os.getpid(), __name__, 'l' in globals())

# A - l = list(range(100000))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # B - l = list(range(100000))
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(process, [1,2,3,4])

    print(os.getpid(), __name__, 'l' in globals())
```

#### On Windows

When uncommenting comment `A`, a printout similar to:

```
19604 __mp_main__ True
6392 __mp_main__ True
19604 __mp_main__ True
7048 __mp_main__ True
6568 __main__ True
```

will be given. This is because the list is defined ***outside*** the `__name__` guard, and as the processes in Windows basically `import` the py file, they all define their own version of `l`.

When uncommenting comment `B`, a printout similar to:

```
7248 __mp_main__ False
22644 __mp_main__ False
22676 __mp_main__ False
16520 __mp_main__ False
19736 __main__ True
```

will be given. i.e. as the the list is defined inside the `__name__` guard, only the `__main__` process have it defined and it passes the arguments through `map` to the different processes.

#### On Linux

Uncommenting any of the comments will give a printout similar to:

```
25261 __main__ True
25262 __main__ True
25263 __main__ True
25264 __main__ True
25260 __main__ True
```

I am guessing that this is because Linux uses `fork` to create the spawned processes, where the processes are being *"cloned"* so the list will be defined either way.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was rather informative. I am using a Linux system, and I'm aware of this forking process. Is there any way to prevent such a list from being cloned each time new processes are spawned?

Comment: Don't use a list. Use dedicated `multiprocessing` objects for shared access. See [Sharing resources between python processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55004267/6045800)

Answer (score 2):

To concretely answer the original question specifically regarding the usage of "spawn" (as OP mentioned they are familiar with "fork")

When a process object is created, it is constructed in `main`, and then a new python process is executed with command line args to share a pair of file handles for communication as well as a stub of code to start from.

That "bootstrap" code will try to `import` the main file, which is both why you need to protect against unintended side-effects on import (`if __name__ == "__main__":`), and why anything outside of that protection is "available" to the child. This primarily is meant to make sure functions from the main file are defined, but any variables defined at the module level are also defined. This is useful for constants as long as it doesn't matter that you're effectively re-computing the values, and making one copy for each process. For large datasets this is very inefficient.

The bootstrap code will also read one of the file handles, and attempt to `unpickle` the process object that the parent sent to it. The target of the process is generally a function you have defined, but care must be taken that it's accessible in the "main" namespace on import (no lambda's, no instance methods, etc..). Python does not serialize code objects with pickle, rather it relays how to properly import the function, which gets dicey with objects that don't have a concrete namespace on import (sidebar, the 3rd party `multiprocess` library attempts to solve this by using `dill` instead of `pickle` to generally good success). This also plays into account when you subclass the `Process` class, and attach other data to a process instance; it all must be pickleable.

Once the process object has been successfully un-pickled by the child process, the `run` method is called. This is generally the entrypoint of your code. with a `Pool`, there's a big class that lives on the main process, and launches "worker" processes with a pre-defined function that takes in "jobs" and returns the results until told to exit. Data (task items consisting of a function to execute and args for that func) is sent to and from the workers via `Queue`s which work pretty much the same as sending the original `Process` object: the thing you put into the queue is pickled, sent via a file handle, and un-pickled in the child.

Comment: Thanks. Sad to not have this great explanation in the documentation.